# What version of windows for Dreamweaver as a service?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, remote-desktop

For a project I need to have a server setup where users can RDP in and access Adobe Dreamweaver which is installed on the server.

What OS should I use?

Can I install **Windows 7 Enterprise** on the server and enable RDP into the server?
Or should I go with **Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter**

I only expect 1 user to be logged in at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one person, then just simply setup the Win7. No need for server OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Server 2008R2 with RDSH (the new version of terminal services). You can publish Dreamweaver as a remote app as well using 2008R2. Windows 7 has many more restriction on the number of concurrent RDP sessions than Server 2008R2 does.